# How to properly cast expected generic-typed arguments?

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I'm lost in generics (Java). The real scenario involves JPA and `CriteriaBuilder`'s

```
<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> Predicate greaterThan(Expression<? extends Y> x, Y y);
```

but I simplified the same case in the following class:

```
public class GenericsTest {

    public class Bean<T> {

    };

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> T targetMethod(Bean<T> bean, T object) {
        return object;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T castToGeneric(Bean<T> bean, Object object) {
        return (T) object;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> void understandGenerics(Bean<T> bean, Object object) {
        Bean<Comparable<T>> beanOfComparable = (Bean<Comparable<T>>) bean;
        Comparable<T> comparableObject = this.castToGeneric(beanOfComparable, object);
        this.targetMethod(beanOfComparable, comparableObject);
    }

}
```

The invocation `targetMethod(beanOfComparable, comparableObject)` in the last line generates

> The method `targetMethod(Bean<T>, T)` in the type
>   `GenericsTest` is not applicable for the arguments
>   `(Bean<Comparable<T>>, Comparable<T>)`

and I don't understand where the problem is, since `T` in `targetMethod` must be a `Comparable<T>`, that is the type I'm giving it.

Answer (score 2):

The constraint on your `targetMethod` is the thing that is causing it to fail:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> T targetMethod(Bean<T> bean, T object)
```

When you pass in the variables `(Bean<Comparable<X>>, Comparable<X>)`, you are implying that the generic parameter T is `Comparable<X>` (I'm using X here to distinguish between the generic from targetMethod and the generic from understandGenerics).

The constraint on `targetMethod` says that when your T is `Comparable<X>`, then T must extend `Comparable<Comparable<X>>`. Of course, this is not going to be satisfied.

I think what you intend to do would be better accomplished like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void understandGenerics(Bean<T> bean, Object object) {
    T comparable = (T) object;
    targetMethod(bean, comparable);
}
```

Notice with the added constraint that T must be comparable, the whole process is much simpler. In general, it pays to limit unchecked code as much as possible, and put constraints on the types instead.